# Unpermitted parameter: songs_attributes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a problem with my nested attributes. I want someone to be able to just visit my website and add songs to an event. They can only add those songs if they supply a partycode for that event. I have my nested attributes set up correctly I think but I am getting an unpermitted paramter error.

Events controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @event = Event.new
        @event.songs.build
    end

    def show
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
      @songs = @event.songs.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def create
        @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
        if @event.save
            flash[:success] = "Event Created!"
            redirect_to user_path(@event.user)
        else
            render 'welcome/index'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private 

      def event_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:name, :partycode, song_attributes: [:artist, :title, :genre, :partycode])
      end
end
```

application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Here is the new.html.erb file in the songs view, which contains the code to add songs to the event, note that the user is not signed in when they are adding songs:

```
<br>
<br>
<div class ="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
  <%= form_for Event.new do |f| %>
    <h3>Enter a song:</h3>
    <%= f.fields_for :songs, Song.new do |song_form| %>

      <%= song_form.collection_select(:event_id, Event.all, :id, :name) %>
      <%= song_form.text_field :artist, placeholder: "Artist" %>
      <%= song_form.text_field :title,  placeholder: "Title" %>
      <%= song_form.text_field :genre,  placeholder: "Genre" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Song", f, :songs %>
    <%= f.text_field :partycode %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The link_to_add_fields method is in the application_helper.rb file:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render("songs_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

The songs_field partial is defined as follows:

```
<fieldset>  
  <%= f.text_field :artist, placeholder: "Artist" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title,  placeholder: "Title" %>
  <%= f.text_field :genre,  placeholder: "Genre" %>
</fieldset>
```

The coffee-script that adds the fields:

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_songs', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('event_id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('songs').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

The person from the new.html.erb page will be able to select a event from the drop down menu then on demand add more fields that are for a song and then enter a partycode for the certain event that they picked. Any help on this would be fantastic! Thanks

EDIT error:

```
undefined method `events' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, there seems to be a wrong singularization/pluralization. Please post `event.rb`, and `song.rb` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `EventsController`, your nested params is spelled as `song_attributes` in `event_params` method

```
private 
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :partycode, song_attributes: [:artist, :title, :genre, :partycode])
  end
```

But your error says `unpermitted parameter: songs_attributes`.

You spelled it incorrect.Change your `event_params` method in `EventsController` as follows

```
private 
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :partycode, songs_attributes: [:artist, :title, :genre, :partycode])
  end
```

Comment: After defining this, I get an error that states that my user is not signed in. I should not need a user to be signed in should I? The error is in my events controller

Comment: Can you update the question with `ApplicationController` code and error snippet?

Comment: Edited, @Pramod